# Colorbox shows under flash

Tags: jquery, css, flash, lightbox, colorbox

I am using jQuery's colorbox to open up an iframe on a page. On the page there are two flash SWFs. When I click the button that opens the colorbox, those flash SWFs appear over the top of my colorbox div. I've checked the CSS properties of the colorbox, and the overlay has `position:absolute` and `z-index:999`. I have given the SWFs a `z-index:0` property, but they still show over the top of the colorbox. This happens in Firefox, IE, and Chrome.

Comment: Does the flash container have a z-index, have you tried setting it to something?

Comment: yes i have tried setting it to 0

Comment: Just wanted to say im new to stackoverflow and didnt see the replies were here, hence why i did the other post. Apologies! Im a spaz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/faq/#faq-flash

Comment: ive tried this but the flash is still showing over the colorbox.

heres the code for one of my flash objects as it stands

<object width="294" height="319" style="float:left; margin-left:0px; margin-top:20px; z-index:0; overflow:hidden;">
<param name="movie" value="/flash/ZOFLORA_HOMEPAGE_BANNER.swf" wmode="transparent">
<embed src='/flash/<umbraco:Item runat="server" field="SmallFlash"/>' width="294" height="319" style="z-index:0;">
</embed>
</object>

Answer (score 7):

For those using the **iframe** embed code from **Youtube** or **Vimeo**, you have to approach it differently. I used the events **onOpen** and **onClosed** to hide and show back the iframe. Here's an example:

```
$('.selector').colorbox({
    inline: true,
    href: '.step.'+target,
    rel: 'steps',
    onOpen: function(){
        $('iframe').css('visibility','hidden');
    },
    onClosed: function(){
    $('iframe').css('visibility','visible');
    },
    loop: false,
    opacity: 0.5
});
```

I guess it also works if you want to apply it to your embed or object tag as a quick solution.

Answer (score 2):

If your problem happens to be Youtube Specific, here is the easiest way I found to fix it:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/b-LJ7pYNI0I?
wmode=transparent" width="590" height="332" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

That is to say, append that final get parameter '?wmode=transparent' to the iframe src.

source: http://groups.google.com/group/slimbox-support/msg/39d42c9e0b6a7093

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your flash is using a window mode that supports z-indexing, such as transparent. This is defined when you start the flash using swfobject, or similar.

Almost certain that this will be the problem, but it could be that you've got the stacking order of the divs a bit confused. **Remember that z-indexing isn't a global hierarchy, it takes the index from the parent element.**

Comment: tried switching to swfobject but when i add wmode property to the param line visual studio says this is not a valid property of param. If i use it anyway the flash still shows over the colorbox. Ive added style="z-index:0;" to the object tag on both flashs and the div containing has z-index-1. these are the only areas on the site where z-index is used apart from the colorbox css where it is set to z-index:999 on every instance.

Comment: Without doubt, the lack of a wmode parameter is what's causing the problem then. Visual studio shouldn't be complaining - perhaps update the code at the top with what you have with swfobject, and we can fix that.

Comment: also try adding this in, instead of what you have above: <param value="transparent" name="wmode">

Answer (score 1):

An alternate version of [Jorge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6024188/95357):

```
onOpen: function(){
  $('embed:visible').css('visibility','hidden').addClass('colorbox-hidden-fix');
},
onClosed: function(){
  $('embed.colorbox-hidden-fix').css('visibility','visible');
}
```

This deals with `embed` elements, if you happen to have such on your pages. It also tries not to show elements that were initially hidden. Should also work with other types, just substitute `embed` with eg. `iframe`.

Comment: To hide flash in IE you have to hide the objects: $('object:visible').css('visibility','hidden').addClass('colorbox-hidden-fix');

Answer (score 1):

If you are using iframe to external site that have flash content, you can use next code.

```
onClosed:function(){
        $('#iframe').attr('src', 'http://iframeurl.com/');
        $('#iframe').show();
},
onOpen:function(){
        $('#iframe').hide();
        $('#iframe').removeAttr('src');
}
```

enjoy.